# How to add horizontal geom_col() with same axis Y and secondary axis X than a geom_line()?

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram, axis, geom-col

I have two kind of data I want to merge with ggplot():

- The main, are two `geom_lines()` of duration vs. iteration in tests.
- The secondary, is a kind of histogram with `geom_col()`: count vs. duration.

I can plot it together but in the histogram the position of the cols has no relation with the duration axis, because it's flipped:

[image: What I get]

What I want, is draw the cols horizontally, in a way that the position of each one is aligned to axis Y (duration). I'm not sure how to proceed, maybe a combination of grobs and secondary axis, but I do not know how. Something like this:
[image: What I want]

The data, scale operations and plot code for this example is:

```
    # TEST DATA:
    tests <- 
    data.frame(iteration=1:20,
               testA=c(0.7399, 0.8103, 0.6779, 0.6608, 0.6755, 0.6842, 0.8423, 0.647, 
                       0.6955, 0.6673, 0.6549, 0.6886, 0.6667, 0.6888, 0.7627, 0.68, 
                       0.6588, 0.678, 0.6816, 0.6811),
               testB=c(0.6185, 0.3757, 0.3633, 0.3532, 0.3517, 0.3611, 0.3487, 0.357, 
                       0.3608, 0.3647, 0.3501, 0.3451, 0.361, 0.379, 0.3841, 0.3703, 
                       0.3595, 0.3463, 0.4046, 0.3462))

    htestA <- data.frame(
      duration = c(0.749, 0.8009, 0.8528, 0.9048, 0.9567, 1.0086, 1.0605, 1.1124, 
                   1.1643, 1.2162, 1.2681, 1.32, 1.372, 1.4239, 1.4758, 1.5277, 
                   1.5796, 1.6315, 1.6834, 1.7353),
      count = c(0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 1, 6, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0)
    )

    htestB <- data.frame(
      duration = c(0.4342, 0.4934, 0.5526, 0.6118, 0.671, 0.7302, 0.7894, 0.8486, 
                   0.9078, 0.967, 1.0261, 1.0853, 1.1445, 1.2037, 1.2629, 1.3221, 
                   1.3813, 1.4405, 1.4997, 1.5589),
      count = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
    )

    # SCALE TO FLIPPED AXIS (histogram duration as X and count Y)
    library(dplyr)

    maxY <- max(tests$testA,tests$testB)
    minD <- min(htestA$duration,htestB$duration)
    maxD <- max(htestA$duration,htestB$duration)
    maxC <- max(htestA$count,htestB$count)
    d2x <- function(d) {(d-minD)*(max(tests$iteration)-min(tests$iteration))/(maxD-minD)+min(tests$iteration)}
    c2y <- function(c) {c*maxY/maxC}
    hA <- mutate(htestA,duration=d2x(duration),count=c2y(count))
    hB <- mutate(htestB,duration=d2x(duration),count=c2y(count))

    # PLOT
    library(ggplot2)
    ggplot(tests,aes(x=iteration)) +
      geom_col(data=hA,aes(duration,count),fill="orange",alpha=0.3) +
      geom_col(data=hB,aes(duration,count),fill="gray",alpha=0.3) +
      geom_line(aes(y=testA),color="red") +
      geom_line(aes(y=testB))
```